# Validation of mixed-effect models

Tags: mixed-model, validation

I want to use linear mixed effect model for a set of data.

After using [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/) package and `lmer()` function and fitting model, I want to validate my model for other period time. But I don't know how to validate my model and generate predicted values.

Do you have any ideas about useful validation method? Is there any command about validation in R software?

---

Thanks for your useful comments.

I fitted model to one set of data and now I want to check its performance for an other data set.
I want to plot figure by "predicted value" and "observed value" and calculate R^2 to evaluate model performance.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? One meaning could be "check assumptions"; another "check that it fits other data". Possible more meanings that that, too.

Comment: agree with @PeterFlom that this question is a bit too vague.  In the meanwhile, you could look at `?predict.merMod` ...

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments.

I fitted model to one set of data and now I want to check its performance for an other data set. I want to plot figure by "predicted value" and "observed value" and calculate R^2 to evaluate model performance.

Thanks